# HTML element no defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html element:

```
<img alt="" src="../Images/ERROR.jpg" id="live1x4" height="288" style="width: 360px;
                                                display: block;" /
```

If i refer to this control  in javascript which is in the same html page:

```
live1x4.src = src;
```

Where src is the location of an image the script works.

If  move that javascript to an external js file I get 'live1x4' is undefined.

This occurs ONLY in Internet Explorer.

Wjat can be causing this error?

Comment: I'd recommend to use `document.getElementById('live1x4')`. You also have to make sure that you are trying to refer to the element when it exists (not before).

Comment: If it works in one file, the element is namespaced to the global object, so the browser should do the same thing in the other file, so chances are high that the other file runs before the element is available, or it's simply in the wrong scope. You should be using getElementById anyway IMO.

Comment: People... thank you for the lesson :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target your element, not simply refer to the ID:

```
document.getElementById("live1x4").src  = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the JavaScript code is executed before the `img` element has been parsed. Whether this happens depends on many things. There are different ways to ensure that it does not happen. A simple way is to wrap your code inside an even handler that is triggered after the document has been loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
   // your code here, here all elements are available, e.g.:
   live1x4.src = src;
}
```

It is generally regarded as bad coding style to use `id` attribute values as if they were global variables (partly because they stop working ifsynonymous global variables are added), so `document.getElementById("live1x4")` is preferable to `live1x4`. However, this is a different topic.